# How can I update the position of a range input slider via vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to programmatically update the position of my input slider (type="range").

I'm setting the value, however, that won't update the position of the slider.

I've also tried using:

`element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))`

to force an input change. This event does fire, however, the slider won't visually update.

```
   function changeSliderPosition(position) {
       let e = document.getElementById('mySlider');
       e.value = position;
       //Also set the position of the slider to position
   }
```

I've seen some solutions that work in JQuery, but I don't want to include an entire library or even use it at all for such a seemingly small issue.

I'd appreciate any help with this problem!

Comment: Please include a [mre] showing the code (JavaScript and HTML) you're using that is not working. As you can see from the answer provided, setting the `value` does indeed update the position of the thumb.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I was doing wrong but I just came back after taking a break and it was working how it should. Not sure why it wasn't working before. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your slider (`input type="range"`) has its `min` and `max` attributes set, all you need to do is set the `value`:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("in");
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
let slider = document.querySelector("input[type='range']");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  slider.value = input.value;
});
```

```html
Enter the value you want: <input id="in"><button>Go!</button><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100">
```