# How to force HTML slider to show its initial value

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I want to create a slider element (input type range) in JavaScript that jumps back to its initial value after release.  In this way I get the behaviour like a joystick that jumps back to its equilibrium position after release.

I now have the following code:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = "range";
element.min = myObject.min;
element.max = myObject.max;
element.step = myObject.step;
valueDiv.className = myObject.type + "_value";
elementDiv.appendChild(valueDiv);
element.defaultValue = myObject.init; //value does not show up in HTML simply because the attribute does not exist
valueDiv.innerHTML = myObject.init;
element.oninput = function() { //use oninput to get values continously during changing (onchange only gives value after mouseup)
  valueDiv.innerHTML = this.value; //display changed value               
}
element.onchange = function() { //use onchange to define an action after release (mouseup) of the slider)
  valueDiv.innerHTML = myObject.init; //display changed value
  // code here to let the element show the position that reflects element.defaultValue
  // this position is only shown after loading the page             
  //code here     //send changed value
}
```

I use the element.oninput event to continuously show the changing value in valueDiv when I draw the slider. The element.onchange event fires when the slider is released (on mouseup). The valueDiv then shows the initial value (element.defaultValue).  I want the position of the slider to reflect this initial value. I did not discover an action/function of the element do that.

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding but why not `element.value = defaultValue`?

Comment: Hi ray,   yes,  assigning a value to element.value will move the slider to the right position. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does! I found that anwer too :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer here:

[How can I update the position of a range input slider via vanilla js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828301/how-can-i-update-the-position-of-a-range-input-slider-via-vanilla-js)   by Scott Marcus

When I add element.value = myObject.init  the slider jumps to the position that fits with the value init.

Comment: Please don't answer a question with a link to a question. Since this is a link to an internal answer, you can quote the relevant parts of the answer, giving appropriate credit, and show how you applied it to your question. Alternatively, if someone votes to close your question as a duplicate of that question, as I have, you can say that the answers did indeed answer your question.